# How do I reference the deserialized list in another method?

Tags: c#, wpf, parameter-passing

This is a newbie question but I need help organizing my code. Here's my giant method.
This method allows the user to browse for an xml file and then deserializes it.

```
public void DeSerializationXML(string filePath)
{
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
    xRoot.IsNullable = false;

    // Create an instance of lotinformation class.
    var lot = new LotInformation();

    // Create an instance of stream writer.
    TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

    // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (LotInformation), xRoot);

    // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
    lot = (LotInformation) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);

    // Close the stream reader
    txtReader.Close();

    //Storing deserialized strings to db
    using (var db = new DMIDataContext())
    {


        LotInformation newLot = new LotInformation();


        if (newLot != null)
        {
            newLot.Id = lot.Id;
            newLot.lot_number = lot.lot_number;
            newLot.exp_date = lot.exp_date;

            LotNumber = newLot.lot_number;
            ExpirationDate = newLot.exp_date.ToString();

            //Grabs the lot_number column from db that is distinct
            var lotNum = db.LotInformation.GroupBy(i => i.lot_number).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());

            //Loops through the lot numbers column in db and converts to list 
            foreach (var item in lotNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.lot_number);
            }
            LotNumList = lotNum.ToList();

            foreach (Components comp in lot.Components)
            {
                newLot.Components.Add(comp);

            }
            ComponentsList = newLot.Components;

            foreach (Families fam in lot.Families)
            {

                newLot.Families.Add(fam);
            }
            FamiliesList = newLot.Families;

            try
            {
                db.LotInformation.Add(newLot);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("successfully");
            }
            catch
            {
                //TODO: Add a Dialog Here

            }
        }

    }
```

Right now, I want to break this method up in two or possibly three methods to simply and clean the code.

Here's what I have done so far:

**Deserialize:**

```
public void DeSerializationXML(string filePath)
{
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
    xRoot.IsNullable = false;

    // Create an instance of lotinformation class.
    var lot = new LotInformation();

    // Create an instance of stream writer.
    TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

    // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation), xRoot);

    // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
    lot = (LotInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);

    // Close the stream reader
    txtReader.Close();
}
```

**StoreInDatabase:**

```
public void StoreStreamInDB(string lot)
{
    //Storing deserialized strings to db
    using (var db = new DMIDataContext())
    {


        LotInformation newLot = new LotInformation();


        if (newLot != null)
        {
            newLot.Id = lot.Id;
            newLot.lot_number = lot.lot_number;
            newLot.exp_date = lot.exp_date;

            LotNumber = newLot.lot_number;
            ExpirationDate = newLot.exp_date.ToString();

            //Grabs the lot_number column from db that is distinct
            var lotNum = db.LotInformation.GroupBy(i => i.lot_number).Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());

            //Loops through the lot numbers column in db and converts to list 
            foreach (var item in lotNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.lot_number);
            }
            LotNumList = lotNum.ToList();

            foreach (Components comp in lot.Components)
            {
                newLot.Components.Add(comp);

            }
            ComponentsList = newLot.Components;

            foreach (Families fam in lot.Families)
            {

                newLot.Families.Add(fam);
            }
            FamiliesList = newLot.Families;

            try
            {
                db.LotInformation.Add(newLot);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("successfully");
            }
            catch
            {
                //TODO: Add a Dialog Here

            }
        }
```

However, the deserialized paramteter lot is not the same as the parameter lot in `StoreStreamInDB()`.
How do I grab the deserialized list from the `deserializationXML()` method and pass the same list to `StoreStreamInDB()`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you return a `LotInformation` from your `DeSerializationXML` and take that in as an argument to your `StoreStreamInDB`?  For example...

```
public static LotInformation ReadLotFromFile(string filePath)
{
    LotInformation lot;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation), new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "lot_information", IsNullable = false });
        lot = (LotInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    return lot;
}

public static void AddLotToDb(LotInformation lot)
{
    using(var db = new DMIDataContext())
    {
        db.LotInformation.Add(lot);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public static void ExampleUsage()
{
    AddLotToDb(ReadLotFromFile("my_lot.xml"));
}
```